# HTML5 / CSS / RWD - deploy four boxes in a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How to deploy four boxes in a div to be positioned at the edges of the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right and when you click the box in the middle to open a window with the text.

Something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3etszqonq9egven/layout.jpg

Help me please

Comment: Show at least some basic effort...

Answer (score 2):

style the div in following way

top-left

```
 <style>margin-top:0;margin-left:0;</style>
```

top-right

```
 <style> margin-top:0;margin-right:0;</style>
```

bottom-left

```
 <style>margin-bottom:0;margin-left:0;</style>
```

bottom-right

```
 <style>margin-bottom:0;margin-right:0;</style>
```